# transferTo Java.nio files with 00's when run through Matlab JVM?

Tags: java, matlab, io, jvm

I'm using matlab jvm with Java.Nio to copy the body of a binary file to another file without the header.

My code is:

```
fromfile = java.io.RandomAccessFile(ifile, 'rw');
fromchannel = fromfile.getChannel();
tofile = java.io.FileOutputStream(ofile);
tochannel = tofile.getChannel();
tochannel.position(0);
fromchannel.transferTo(n,fromfile.length()-n,tochannel);

tochannel.close();
fromchannel.close();
fromfile.close();
tofile.close();
```

and what I want is a hexadecimal start with 7F 7F (the start of my body after header) but what I'm getting is:

```
000004e0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000004f0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000500h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000510h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000520h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000530h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7F 7F 2F ; ............./
00000540h: 07 00 07 14 00 4F 00 90 00 12 03 54 04 96 05 D8 ; .....O....T.–.Ø
```

Etc...Etc...

Why is it outputting like this? I can't get it to write properly?

EDIT 001.

the matlab function I'm using is:

```
function TrimBinary(ifile,ofile,n)

fromfile = java.io.RandomAccessFile(ifile, 'rw');
fromchannel = fromfile.getChannel();
tofile = java.io.FileOutputStream(ofile);
tochannel = tofile.getChannel();
tochannel.position(0);
fromchannel.transferTo(n,fromfile.length()-n,tochannel);

tochannel.close();
fromchannel.close();
fromfile.close();
tofile.close();

end
```

My test input is:

```
00000000h: 05 FF 49 FF F4 FD 13 FF A5 FD A5 20 AC FD 55 FE ; .ÿIÿôý.ÿ¥ý¥ ¬ýUþ
00000010h: 67 FE C7 FF BE FD 75 FE CF FE 28 20 A1 FD 3F FE ; gþÇÿ¾ýuþÏþ( ¡ý?þ
00000020h: 1C FD 4B 20 D0 FD 49 FF 62 FF E7 FF 79 FD CF FE ; .ýK ÐýIÿbÿçÿyýÏþ
00000030h: 20 FD 31 FE 31 FE 46 FE C2 FC EF FE 52 FD F0 FD ;  ý1þ1þFþÂüïþRýðý
00000040h: 40 FD 37 FF 2A FD A5 FD 2F FC EA FF FB FD 92 FE ; @ý7ÿ*ý¥ý/üêÿûý’þ
00000050h: 8C FC 20 80 20 80 83 FE 81 FD 3E FF 39 FD D3 FD ; Œü € €ƒþý>ÿ9ýÓý
00000060h: F1 FC 5E FC 34 FE 79 FD 83 FB 7F 7F 99 FE 2A FD ; ñü^ü4þyýƒû™þ*ý
00000070h: 20 FD AF FD 7A FC 20 80 2A FD 35 FD 20 80 20 80 ;  ý¯ýzü €*ý5ý € €
00000080h: F1 FC AA FB 20 80 20 80 FF FC 12 FC 20 80 20 80 ; ñüªû € €ÿü.ü € €
00000090h: 46 FE D1 FC 20 80 20 80 20 80 5D FD 01 FF 76 FD ; FþÑü € € €]ý.ÿvý
000000a0h: FB FD E6 FC 30 02 40 FD F4 FD A4 FE BA 01 20 80 ; ûýæü0.@ýôý¤þº. €
000000b0h: 46 FE 7B FF AB 01 57 FC BC FF 57 FF 6B 01 80 FE ; Fþ{ÿ«.Wü¼ÿWÿk.€þ
000000c0h: 61 20 3E FF 58 02 68 FD 62 FF 69 FF 4A 01 D3 FD ; a >ÿX.hýbÿiÿJ.Óý
000000d0h: E1 FE 0C FF EA FF 55 FE 49 FF 51 FE EE FF 93 FD ; áþ.ÿêÿUþIÿQþîÿ“ý
000000e0h: F8 20 E2 FD 25 FF CD FC 05 FF 80 FE BE FD D8 FC ; ø âý%ÿÍü.ÿ€þ¾ýØü
```

My function Call:

```
TrimBinary('testin.000','testout.000',106)
```

My Output:

```
00000000h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000010h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000020h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000030h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000040h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000050h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000060h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7F 7F 99 FE 2A FD ; ..........™þ*ý
00000070h: 20 FD AF FD 7A FC 20 80 2A FD 35 FD 20 80 20 80 ;  ý¯ýzü €*ý5ý € €
00000080h: F1 FC AA FB 20 80 20 80 FF FC 12 FC 20 80 20 80 ; ñüªû € €ÿü.ü € €
00000090h: 46 FE D1 FC 20 80 20 80 20 80 5D FD 01 FF 76 FD ; FþÑü € € €]ý.ÿvý
000000a0h: FB FD E6 FC 30 02 40 FD F4 FD A4 FE BA 01 20 80 ; ûýæü0.@ýôý¤þº. €
000000b0h: 46 FE 7B FF AB 01 57 FC BC FF 57 FF 6B 01 80 FE ; Fþ{ÿ«.Wü¼ÿWÿk.€þ
000000c0h: 61 20 3E FF 58 02 68 FD 62 FF 69 FF 4A 01 D3 FD ; a >ÿX.hýbÿiÿJ.Óý
000000d0h: E1 FE 0C FF EA FF 55 FE 49 FF 51 FE EE FF 93 FD ; áþ.ÿêÿUþIÿQþîÿ“ý
000000e0h: F8 20 E2 FD 25 FF CD FC 05 FF 80 FE BE FD D8 FC ; ø âý%ÿÍü.ÿ€þ¾ýØü
```

What I want is that the file starts with "7F 7F", not "00 00"?

What's going on?

Comment: What is the value of `n` here? And can you replace your pseudo-code with real code? (You're currently calling a constructor as if it were a method...)

Comment: n is 1341. this is how you write the code in matlab to utilize the internal jvm.

Comment: Oh - it would have been useful to explain that you're doing so, given that your question is only tagged `java` and `io`... please bear in mind relevant context when asking questions in future.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, do you think thats the reason?? Because Im using matlabs jvm??

Comment: No, I never said that. I just said that it's helpful to have the context - if you're going to provide code which isn't valid Java in a question which is only tagged `java`, that's going to confuse anyone reading the question. Ideally, you should try to reproduce this in "normal" Java, providing a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: (For what it's worth, I've just tried doing the same thing in plain Java and it's been fine.)

Comment: Is there any other easier method to deleting the start of a file in Java? If you could point me to the right direction?

Comment: No, this seems a reasonable way of doing it.

Comment: but this isn't working for me? Can I open the files as buffers??

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "buffers" here - but as I said, I'd try to reproduce the problem in plain Java first. Maybe it *is* a matlab implementation issue - but it's hard to say at the moment.

Comment: I doubt that's a MATLAB issue. MATLAB isn't implementing any of this on its own, its using the JVM. The result should be no different from doing it in plain java. Have you made sure that `n` has the proper value?

Comment: Just tested it in MATLAB and it works just fine.

Comment: @sebastian look at my new edit please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to stem from running internal jvm through matlab on linux.... I ran the same code on a windows matlab and it worked fine. I probably should have put that im running linux matlab in the Question but I though Java (all the talk about portability) would run exactly the same on either OS (cept for like some memory managment stuff), but aparently not for writing files????? Ill post another question to see if anyone knows a good reason why??

Thanks

Comment: Alex, please read my last comment on your deleted QA. I saw no problem with such QA and didn't vote to close it. Before voting, I comment and wait so the poster can offer an explanation or improve the post.  Please understand that I was on your side, and I only wanted an opportunity for you to improve the QA before more downvotes rolled in. You don't believe it, but I'm actually the good guy here...